# Can i use multistorage and CSVExcelStorage at the same time (or close) in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I'm looking a way to store a relation into splitted folders in a CSV format.
I'm launching the pig from a shell.

I looked on stack but I don't found anything speaking about this case.

I'm using the piggybank 0.14 and the java of the last multistorage to use the multifield selection.

If I use the CSVExcelStorage to store the relation, I can cut the output file in shell, but I think this action will make me lost the CSV format.

If I use the multiStorage to store the relation, I'm not able to format the output file in CSV.

So, is it possible to apply the CSVExcelStorage from a Relation to a Relation?

Do you have any other suggestion?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to SO!

Have a good read here and come back and edit the question:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fine, i used a shell to simulate the multistorage with some filter and CSVExcelStorage.

```
sklt="file.pig.skeleton"
pig="file.pig"
cp ${sklt} ${pig}

for waza in $anOtherVar
do
    echo "R2 = R1 FILTER JEANNO IN ('${waza}')" >> ${pig}
    echo -e "STORE R2 INTO '$myPath/${waza}' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(';');\n" >> ${pig}
done
pig -f ${pig} -p table=$anOtherVar -p myPath=/past/a/box/
```

if this awesome solution can help some other pig addict...